# Q: How do you Display Chinese characters in command prompt

Tags: text-files, command-prompt

Is it possible to display chinese characters in command prompt? if so what are the settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it's some settings in CMD
the default CMD doesn't support the unicode characters(including all other languages than English)
I don't know how to do it
But you can search about it "make CMD support unicode"

Answer (score 16):

If you need to read simplified Chinese (GBK) which is code page 936

Enter the following command in the dos prompt

```
chcp 936
```

##### Update

Microsoft introduced a new Terminal app (https://aka.ms/terminal) which supports Unicode and Emoji fonts. It also allows us to customize different profiles for different consoles (such as Dos, PowerShell, Ubuntu, etc.).

The Terminal app use Cascadia Mono with font size 12 as default. We can change it for different profiles via `settings.json` which is accessed via Settings and clicking on the [image] icon.

Below shows a view of the `settings.json`:

[image]

Comment: Are there other fonts I can use?