# Print unicode symbols to cmd

Tags: c++, windows, cmd

I want print unicode symbols to cmd for OS Windows. My unicode string saved to `std::string`, which readed from file. I can write and read unicode string from file to `std::string`. But, how print and write unicode string with helps cmd (OS Windows)?
I tryed:

```
#include <windows.h>

SetConsoleOutputCP(encoding); // 65001, 1251, 1252
// and set from cmd font 'Lucida Console'
```

But this don't work, as some symbols no showing (China etc).

P.S.: sorry! I want use `cout` and `cin` operator

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2492077/output-unicode-strings-in-windows-console-app).

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52355476/421195

Comment: std::string is not appropiate for storing a unicode string. Use std::wstring together with std::wcout for output and std::wcin for input instead.