# My C program writes hello, world in Chinese but all I get for output is a blank line

Tags: c

I am trying to learn how to use non-ascii (i.e., wide) characters in my C programs.

I figured that I would start with a C program that writes hello, world in Chinese.

Below is my program. It compiles fine but when I run it (from a Windows command line) I just get a blank line. I am thinking that either (a) my program is not correct, or (b) I have to do something to my Windows command screen for it to display Chinese. Do you know which is the case?

```
#include <wchar.h>

int main()
{
    wchar_t *helloworld = L"你好，世界";
    wprintf_s(L"%s\n", helloworld);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39551549/q-how-do-you-display-chinese-characters-in-command-prompt/52355476

Comment: Actually, part of it might be the code. I think for long strings you have to use %S as opposed to %s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For long strings you have to use %S as opposed to %s.

Comment: Thank you @ExaltedBagel. You are spot-on with %S being the right format conversion. As for setting the Windows command, the use of chcp 936 didn't work. I am now getting output (due to %S) but the output is gibberish (due to chcp 936).